# Every element in the alternating group $A_n$ can be written as a product of at most $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ three-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm looking for a reference in a published paper or book of the following fact.

> Consider an element $\sigma \in A_n$, where $A_n$ is the alternating group on $n$ elements, and $n\geq 3$. Then $\sigma$ can be written as the product of at most $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ three-cycles.

I already know that this is true (it is just an induction on $n$ with some cases depending on the cycle-type of the element $\sigma$). However, I would be grateful if somebody can help me find a reference for this. When I look around I find a lot of material about $A_n$ being generated by $3$-cycles, but nothing about this "minimal number".

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Since you know how to prove it, and the proof is a straightforward induction, why do you need a reference?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154639/how-do-i-use-lemmas-that-are-probably-already-proven-but-including-the-proof-my

Comment: The main answer is just because I am curious about possible generalizations of this question (something related to minimality but for other groups), and probably a reference for that question would also help with my curiosity.
In the practical instance of the problem, I would like to add it as a note to a work that is not about group theory, and the proof - even if it's simple - seems a bit out of place there.

Comment: Let $\sigma\in A_n$. The case $\sigma=1$ is trvial. Let $(a_1\,a_2\,\ldots\,a_m)$ be a maximal cycle of $\sigma$. If $m>2$, then $\sigma\circ (a_1\,a_2\,a_3)^{-1}$ leaves $a_1,a_2$ fixed,  hence after reindexing can be viewed as eleemnt of $A_{n-2}$, and by induction hypothesis is the product of $\le \lfloor \frac{n-2}2\rfloor$ three-cycles. If $m=2$, then all cycles are 2-cycles, and there is at least one other 2-cycle $(b_1\,b_2)$. This time $\sigma\circ(b_1\,a_1\,b_2)(a_1\,a_2\,b_1) $ can be viewed as element of $A_{n-4}$ and the claim follows from the induction hypothesis again.$\square$

Comment: ... and now you can use the above SE comment as reference :). -- But seriously, I am surprised that this seems to occur nowhere, when it at least seems to be a nice exercise in a group theory course

Comment: Yes, it's a reasonable exercise. It is not impossible that it can be found in a textbook somewhere, most likely as an exercise rather than as a stated result, but it might be difficult to find it!

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: that's clever!!
From a certain point of view clearly it is "just" an exercise, but from another, we can fix a group G and a conjugacy class C. Assume C generates G; then we can ask the question "what is the minimum number k of elements in C such that every g in G can be written as a product of at most k elements in C?" And (with better formalism), one can consider words in G with certain properties (e.g. lenght k, types of elements in conjugacies classes,... ) and then ask which elements of G can be expressed with this word. So there could be something interesting there